# How to assign a context-variable to a property with the same name in QML?

Tags: qml, qtquick2, shadowing

This is the result of the following code:

[image: Line 1234, Line 0, Line 0, Line 0]

#### main.qml

```js
import QtQuick 2.8 

Item {
    Reusable {
        index: 1234      // reusable with a custom index
    }   

    ListView {
        anchors { fill: parent; margins: 20; topMargin: 50 }
        model: 3

        // Reusable with an index given by the ListView
        delegate: Reusable {
            index: index // <- does not work, both 'index' point to 
                         //    the index property
        }   
    }   
}
```

#### Reusable.qml

```js
import QtQuick 2.8 

Text {
    property int index
    text: "Line " + index
}
```

## Problem description:

The `ListView` assigns 0, 1, 2, etc. to the variable `index` on every iteration. However, because I am assigning this to a property, this variable is shadowed and I cannot access it.

If I remove `property int index` from `Reusable.qml`, the `ListView` works, but using `Reusable` outside of the ListView does not work anymore.

Is there a way to assign `index: index`?

(I could rename the property which would work, but I would like to avoid that.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can address the model related data through a `model` prefix.

```
ListView {
    model: 3

    delegate: Reusable { index: model.index }
}
```

My recommendation would to do that even if there is no ambiguity, as means to readability. I.e. a developer reading the code can immediately see which data is a local property and which data is provided by the model.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! QML still feels a bit mysterious to me with no obvious way to detect such things. [It is documented, but not easy to find.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#qml-data-models)

Comment: @GeorgSchölly yes, unforunately this approach isn't used through-out the documentation and examples :/